# M-shift-RET does not produce another todo in org-mode

Tags: emacs

I am working on Org-mode to practice TODO,

when in GUI console,

I issue M-shift-RET, it produce another ** TODO

```
* Tasks
** TODO 
** TODO 
** DONE Start new org file for tutorial
   CLOSED: [2018-12-30 Sun 21:04]
```

However, when working on Terminal

```
** DONE Start new org file for tutorial                                                                                                  
    CLOSED: [2018-12-30 Sun 21:01]                                                                                                        
 ** TODO                                                                                                                                  
 **
```

It produce ** as M-RET rather than M-shift-RET

How could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many hot keys work well in GUI-emacs will not work in terminal-emacs. You can  [learn something and find fix method here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal). But the easiest way is to [use GUI-emacs instead of terminal-emacs](https://blog.aaronbieber.com/2016/12/29/don-t-use-terminal-emacs.html).